# python BCD format into Struct

Tags: python, struct

I have the below code in CPP that I am trying to port to Python to send data to a UDPS

```
#define VERSION_MAIN                "V6.60"
#define VERSION_BIN_MAJOR           0x06
#define VERSION_BIN_MINOR           0x60

unsigned char temp[3];


temp[0] = VERSION_MAIN[0];
temp[1] = VERSION_BIN_MAJOR;
temp[2] = VERSION_BIN_MINOR;
```

I have tried code like the following:

```
byteone = bytes(VERSION_MAIN, 'utf-8') 

hex_string = '0x06'
decimal_int = int(hex_string, 16)
decimal_string = str(decimal_int)
digits = [int(c) for c in decimal_string]
zero_padded_BCD_digits = [format(d, '04b') for d in digits]
s = ''.join(zero_padded_BCD_digits)

bytetwo = bytes(int(s[i : i + 8], 2) for i in range(0, len(s), 8))

hex_string = '0x60'
decimal_int = int(hex_string, 16)
decimal_string = str(decimal_int)
digits = [int(c) for c in decimal_string]
zero_padded_BCD_digits = [format(d, '04b') for d in digits]
s = ''.join(zero_padded_BCD_digits)

bytethree = bytes(int(s[i : i + 8], 2) for i in range(0, len(s), 8))

values = (byteonw,bytetwo,bytethree )
s= struct.Struct(f'!3B')
packed_data = s.pack(*values)
```

but I keep getting pesky errors

```
struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

Can anyone give me a hand please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to convert **V** into an `int`, `pack` can manage the `char` type as well.

```
from struct import pack

VERSION_MAIN = "V6.60"
VERSION_BIN_MAJOR = 0x06
VERSION_BIN_MINOR = 0x60

version = pack("!c2B", VERSION_MAIN[0].encode('utf-8'), VERSION_BIN_MAJOR, VERSION_BIN_MINOR)

# version = b'V\x06`'
```

Comment: Thanks for this man, using this i also learned that i was also trying to encode an encoded struct.
God help me